# como pasar por parametro un modelo a otro controlador en yii 2

Tags: php, yii2

En un controlador construi un modelo de tipo Persona y necesito enviarlo a otro controlador y mostrarlo en su vista correspondiente
Intente con el redirect() pero luego no se como mostrarlo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podes aclarar que intentaste o investigaste al respecto?

Answer (score 0):

Desde el controlador inicial, has un redirect y pasa el id del modelo por parametro

```
$this->redirect(['/controlador2/vista', 'id'=> $model->id]);
```

Luego en el controlador2

```
  function actionVista($id) {
    $persona = Persona::findOne($id);
    ...
  }
```